# PYTHON: Annotate boxes disapear dependant on range

Tags: python, matplotlib, annotations

I have an issue plotting the info boxes of some data and a fit. A toy example is as follows.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#Works
sigma = 0.12
mu = 0.5

#Half Works
sigma = 0.1
mu = 0.3

##None Works
#sigma = 0.05
#mu = 0.2

Sample = np.random.normal(mu, sigma, 10000)

figHS = plt.figure() 
axHS = figHS.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
n, histbins, patches = axHS.hist(Sample,100, histtype='step', normed=1) 
axHS.annotate("$\mu=%.3f$ \n $\sigma=%.3f$ \n $N=%i$"%
              (Sample.mean(), Sample.std(), len(Sample)),
              xytext=(0.8, 0.85), bbox=dict(boxstyle="sawtooth", fc="w"),
              xy=(0.8, 0.85), textcoords='axes fraction')
axHS.plot(histbins, plt.mlab.normpdf(histbins, mu, sigma))
axHS.annotate(" $\mu=%.3f$ \n $\sigma=%.3f$ \n $N=%s$"%(mu,sigma,"--"),
              xytext=(0.6, 0.85), bbox=dict(boxstyle="round", fc="w"),
              xy=(0.6, 0.85), textcoords='axes fraction')
plt.show()
```

If you try with the three different input values, you can see that it has something to do with the x-range. It is likely handled differently below 1 or takes the range from the wrong object. Since this is a toy example I am more constrained in my actual use case so please do not suggest I do this in a completely different way unless the values like "histbins" are passed in a similar way.

The desired result is achieved from the first input value.
[image]

But not the second input value:
[image]

Or the third input value:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an issue discussed before, [see](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/1311/)

```
def anno_example(sigma, mu):
    Sample = np.random.normal(mu, sigma, 10000)

    figHS = plt.figure(figsize=(9,6)) 
    axHS = figHS.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
    n, histbins, patches = axHS.hist(Sample,100, histtype='step', normed=1) 

    axHS.plot(histbins, plt.mlab.normpdf(histbins, mu, sigma))

    axHS.annotate("$\mu=%.3f$ \n $\sigma=%.3f$ \n $N=%i$"%
                  (Sample.mean(), Sample.std(), len(Sample)),
                  xytext=(0.8, 0.85), bbox=dict(boxstyle="sawtooth", fc="w"),
                  xy=(0.8, 0.85), xycoords=axHS.transAxes)
    axHS.annotate(" $\mu=%.3f$ \n $\sigma=%.3f$ \n $N=%s$"%(mu,sigma,"--"),
                  xytext=(0.6, 0.85), bbox=dict(boxstyle="round", fc="w"),
                  xy=(0.6, 0.85), xycoords=axHS.transAxes)

anno_example(0.12, 0.5)
anno_example(0.1,  0.3)
anno_example(0.05, 0.2)
```

[image]
[image]
[image]

Just replace `textcoords="axes fraction"` with `xycoords=axHS.transAxes` or `xycoords="axes fraction"` and it works.

Comment: Yes, of course, please do.  I thought it would be an easy fix and apparently am wrong.  The code is in `matplotlib/text.py` file, which it is not that long.  Still, I can't find where it might went wrong after looking at it for a while.

Comment: I have never reported a bug and do not know how to.

Comment: Actually just like a post a question on SO, go to Github, post a new post under the 'issue' tab.  But I just found it has been talked about already: https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/1311/  I will add that to my answer.